# Not able to delete input in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using a script to format the input for my textbox. I only want to use the characters `-` and `.` 1 time and only be able to add numbers into this textbox. After editing I want to round the input to 2 decimals.

I have no problems with the input.

When I want to delete the input I run into problems.

I am not able to delete the input in Mozilla Firefox. I dont have any issues in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.

Does someone know how I can solve this issue?

Here is my script:

```
<input type="text" class="groupOfTexbox" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function setTwoNumberDecimal(el) {
    el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.groupOfTexbox').keypress(function (event) {
      return isNumber(event, this)
    });
  });

  function isNumber(evt, element) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (
      (charCode != 45 || $(element).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&
      (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;
    return true;
  }    
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zduh3a7/1/

Comment: Where is the code which delete the input??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Its just the Backspace key :)

Comment: OK..Sorry @John :)

Comment: As I remember the keycode on Firefox is different with chrome and IE. You should `console.log` in these browser as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include backspace (code = 8) into your whitelist:

```
function isNumber(evt, element) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if ((charCode != 45 || $(element).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&
    (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&
    (charCode != 8)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Also note that it's better to use `keydown`/`keyup` instead of `keypress` for such cases. It seems that IE and Chrome doesn't trigger `keypress` events for some special keys like backspace. That's why your code works in IE and Chrome even without whitelisting backspace key code.